# How to prove the following inequality (Poisson R.V.)

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I need help to prove the following inequality

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P(X=n)\log\left\{n^K\cdot P(X=n)\right\}\geq0
$$
where $K>1$, and $X$ is a Poission R.V. with parameter $\lambda>0$.

---

Edit: the sum should start from $n=1$ and not $n=0$ as it was before.

Thank you!

Comment: Something is wrong here. $n^K$ is 0 at $n=0$ so you're taking the logarithm of 0.

Comment: @Alex Right, now this issue is fixed. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This does not hold.

Let $x_n=\lambda^{n+1}/n!$ for every $n\geqslant0$. If $K=1$, $\log(n^KP(X=n))=-\lambda+\log x_{n-1}$ hence the inequality to prove is equivalent to
$$
\sum_{n\geqslant1}x_{n}\log(x_{n-1})\geqslant\lambda\sum_{n\geqslant1}x_{n}.
$$
If $\lambda\lt1$, $0\lt x_n\lt1$ for every $n\geqslant0$ hence the LHS is negative while the RHS is positive. Thus the inequality fails for $K=1$. By continuity, it also fails for every $K\gt1$ small enough.